# Join 2 columns of a dataframe based on syntax of values in the 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python dataframe and I am trying to combine the cells in the first 2 columns IF the first column value is a string with letters, and the second column value has the syntax of parentheses-single digit-parentheses.

eg: this is the current layout

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | (5) | moretext |

this is what I want the result to be:

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| text (5) | moretext |

I tried using the str.join() function but it's not working for me.

`df1 = df.iloc[:, 0:1].str.join(r'(\(\d\))')`

please let me know how I can write this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe `join` is suppose to join lists (which are inside one column) into a string and not several columns into a unique column (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html)

I might not have understood your problem completely but maybe this could work :

```
idx = df[(df[0].str.contains('\w') & df[1].str.contains('\(\d\)'))].index.values  # find the indices that matches your criteria
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1[0] = df[0][idx] + ' ' + df[1][idx] # merges values of your columns for the proper indices
df1[1] = df[2][idx]
```